# php pdo update query in localhost work not in server centOS

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
if ($status == 'login') {
            $query = "UPDATE login SET is_online = '1', "
                    . "ip_address = :ip_add,login_time = now(),logout_time = '' WHERE username = :username";
            $update = $dbh->prepare($query);
            $update->bindValue(":ip_add", $ip_address, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $update->bindValue(":username", $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        } else {
            $query = "UPDATE login SET is_online = '0',logout_time = now() WHERE username = :username";
            $update = $dbh->prepare($query);
            $update->bindValue(":username", $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }

        echo "====".$update->execute()."++++";
        if ($update->execute()) {
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
```

Above query works in localhost and when i deploy it in server it is not running.

How to i know it is not running?
The `echo echo "====".$update->execute()."++++";` doesnt show anything(even the `= or +`). I am expecting it to print `0 or 1` between the `=,+` whether the query is `fail or passed`.
I cant tell why the execute is not being executed or what.
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: what is in the php error log?  do you have PDO module installed for php on the centos server?

Comment: @flauntster yes i have another select before this one and it works ok. that is why i dont have any idea what is going in here i looks ok. but to be sure i will check for pdo in server.. give me a minute

Comment: looks ok because i get this `pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
readline` when i run php -m @flauntster

Comment: Have you tried checking for an `$update->error()` value? ...or using a `try`/`catch` statement to display errors?

Comment: Before the echo, block your $update->execute in a try/catch block (catching Exception , not just PDOException) ... and take a look there. Also, the way you wrote this, you will execute twice the query if it executes.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg i will try it give me a minute

Comment: @YvesLeBorg execute twice what do you mean? the echo is for testing only i will remove it later on after solving the problem

Comment: @YvesLeBorg i solve it now thanks to your suggestion it was in the date time in database using `''` in timestamp it is not allowed. if you put an answer i would gladly accept it as it help me solve the problem..also include what you mean by it will execute twice..

Comment: nah ... you should answer and accept your own answer so that the question will be tagged as answered in the lists. I could suggest you **[read this interesting blog](https://blog.regehr.org/archives/199)** on debugging.  Good luck with your project.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg thank you for the help. I was debugging the wrong way. now i have a new tool to debug thanks to you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help from **@YvesLeBorg**

I wrap my query in `try/catch PDOException` from there i saw that there is an error saying a column cannot have value of `''`. Which points to the column `logout_time` which is structured `timestamp` so i just change the value to `0000-00-00 00:00:00` and now it works just fine.

Also suggested by same User visit this : [How to Debug](https://blog.regehr.org/archives/199)

Comment: I would alter the table to use `NULL` rather than a non-existent datetime.

Comment: @chris85 you mean i will set the default to null instead? then in my `logout_time = ''` will be ok? or set it to null?

Comment: Set it to `null`, `''` and `null` aren't the same.